# What can these horizontal lines be caused by?

Tags: print-quality, anet-a8

I have changed stock Anet A8 board (Anet v1.5) to new SKR 1.4 with TMC2209. Then I found out these lines on the walls, I don't know how to determine it. Previously this wasn't so visible, but now it bothers pretty much.

[image: Benchy with layer lines prominently shown]

[image: Calibration Cube with layer lines prominently shown]

Comment: Does this happen when printing with different filaments as well? Is the calibration cube dimensionally accurate? Please post settings report with M503 command for more info.

Comment: Please tag your printer, some printers have inherent problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an over/under extrusion. This can be fixed by:

- decreasing/increasing your extrusion multiplier (flow)

[image: Flow parameter in Cura]

- lowering your print temperature

[image]

- checking the diameter of your filament. Do you use the correct diameter?

[image: Diameter option of material in Cura]

Comment: I tried different values of Flow i.e. 90,95,100% - I think 95 works the best. I use the same printing temperature as you and the same filament diameter. Also i calibrated e-steps. I have been trying to solve this problem for several days and I have no idea.